# C++ - Copy Assignment Operator is Implicitly Deleted

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use copy assignment in the following case.

There're two template classes, `list map` and `xpair`.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less=xless<Key>>
class listmap {
public:
   using key_type = Key;
   using mapped_type = Value;
   using value_type = xpair<const key_type, mapped_type>;     //value_type
...
}

template <typename First, typename Second>
struct xpair {
   First first{};
   Second second{};
   xpair(){}
   xpair (const First& first, const Second& second):
           first(first), second(second) {}
};
```

In the main.cpp, I tried to write,

```
using commend = string;
using str_str_map = listmap<string,string>;
using str_str_pair = str_str_map::value_type;    //value_type, to be replaced
using commend_pair = xpair<commend, str_str_pair>;

int main(...) {
   commend_pair cmd_pair;
   str_str_pair newPair ("Key", "value");
   cmd_pair.second = newPair;

   ...
}
```

It gives me an error saying

```
  object of type 'xpair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>,
  std::__1::basic_string<char> >' cannot be assigned because its copy
  assignment operator is implicitly deleted
```

If I replace

```
using str_str_pair = str_str_map::value_type;
```

to

```
using str_str_pair = xpair<string, string>;
```

Everything works fine. Why is that? Shouldn't `value_type = xpair<string, string>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see where `newPair` is declared, but the error message seems like enough.

**Why this fails:** If either element in the `pair` is const, the assignment operator for that element is itself deleted.  You couldn't assign to a `const string` but that's exactly what you're asking it to do when you assign to `pair<const string, T>`.  To simplify the example

```
std::pair<const int, int> p(0, 0);
p.first = 1; // no, can't assign to p.first
p = std::pair<const int, int>(1, 2); // no, requires assigning to p.first
```

**Why maps have `const` key types**: `map` containers organize their elements based of the keys. If you changed a key, the map wouldn't be able to find it anymore.  Consider:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m = { ... };
auto it = m.find(k);
it->first = "a different value";
```

Since a `std::map` for example, is internally organized as a red-black tree, changing the key safely would require a reorganization of the node. However in this example you're operating directly on the `pair` in the node. Changing the `key` would require removing the pair from `m`, then putting it back in with a changed `key`.

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
using value_type = xpair<const key_type, mapped_type>;
```

Since you are using a `const key_type` you are no longer able to assign to it since `key_type` is `const`.

```
using str_str_pair = xpair<string, string>;
```

Works as neither `string` is `const`

Comment: ty for the answer. Is there any way to just use the first one? So it can be a string or int or anything else.