# C++ operator = implicitely deleted

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a wanderer attribute of my class Wanderer in my environmentGame.

I declare it in the environmentGame hpp file :

`Wanderer gaspard;`

And then I initialise it in my GameEnvironment cpp file :

```cpp
void GameEnvironment::initWanderer()
{
    this->gaspard = Wanderer(this->_magic, this->_sphere, this->_textureProgram);
}
```

I have this error :
in gameEnvironment

> use of deleted function ‘Wanderer& Wanderer::operator=(Wanderer&&)’GCC
> Wanderer.hpp(12, 7): ‘Wanderer& Wanderer::operator=(Wanderer&&)’ is implicitly deleted >because the default definition would be ill-formed:

in Wanderer

> use of deleted function ‘Object& Object::operator=(Object&&)’GCC
> Object.hpp(13, 7): ‘Object& Object::operator=(Object&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the >default definition would be ill-formed:

in Object

> non-static reference member ‘ObjectProgram& Object::_program’, can’t use default >assignment operatorGCC

If I declare `std::vector<Wanderer> gaspard;`
and then I push_back a wanderer in my init function
`this->gaspard = Wanderer(this->_magic, this->_sphere, this->_textureProgram);`
It works. But I need only one wanderer so it's not a very good option to have a vector.

Here is the class Wanderer :

```cpp
class Wanderer : public Object 
{ 
    private :  

    public : 
        Wanderer();
        Wanderer(std::vector<FacesGroup> model, std::vector<FacesGroup> lodModel, ObjectProgram& program);

        // void init(std::vector<FacesGroup> facesGroup, ObjectProgram& program);
        void update_position(const TrackballCamera& viewMatrix); 

};
```

Wanderer inherits from

```cpp
class Object 
{

    private : 

    protected : 
        glm::vec3 _position ; 
        float _scale  = 0.1 ; 
        std::vector<std::vector<FacesGroup>> _models; 
        ObjectProgram& _program; 
        // ShadowMapProgram& _shadowMapProgram;
        float _angle = 0.f;
        int _lod = 0; 


    public : 
        Object(std::vector<FacesGroup> model, std::vector<FacesGroup> lodModel, ObjectProgram& program);
        Object();
        // ~Object();
        
        void checkLOD();
        void deleteVAO_VBO();

        glm::vec3 getPosition() const; 
        void draw(const glm::mat4 ViewMatrix, const int windowWidth, const int windowHeight, std::map<std::string, Material>& materialMap, glm::vec3 wandererPos, int color); 

    };
```

And finaly ObjectProgram :

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "p6/p6.h"

struct ObjectProgram
{
    p6::Shader _Program;

    GLint      uMVPMatrix;
    GLint      uMVMatrix;
    GLint      uNormalMatrix;

    GLint uTexture;

    GLint uKd;
    GLint uKs;
    GLint uShininess;

    GLint uLightPos_vs;
    GLint uLightDir_vs;
    GLint uLightCharacter_vs;
    GLint uLightIntensity;

    ObjectProgram() : _Program(p6::load_shader("shaders/3D.vs.glsl", "shaders/texture.fs.glsl"))
    {
        uMVPMatrix    = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uMVPMatrix");
        uMVMatrix     = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uMVMatrix");
        uNormalMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uNormalMatrix");
        
        uTexture = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uTexture");

        uKd        = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uKd");
        uKs        = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uKs");
        uShininess = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uShininess");

        uLightPos_vs    = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uLightPos_vs");
        uLightDir_vs    = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uLightDir_vs");
        uLightCharacter_vs    = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uLightCharacter_vs");
        uLightIntensity = glGetUniformLocation(_Program.id(), "uLightIntensity");
    }
};
```

I saw several topics of this error but none of them seemed to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator

Comment: @MarekR Not 100% the correct link. This is the link to the move assignment related stuff: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator

Comment: `ObjectProgram& _program;` is an issue. `T has a non-static data member of a reference type;`

Comment: I'm wondering how you defined `Object::Object()`, since there doesn't seem to be anything to initialize `_program` with. Note: if you need move assignment for `Object`, you need to go with a pointer (or `std::reference_wrapper`) here instead of a reference to make the member variable reassignable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - Copy Assignment Operator is Implicitly Deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299985/c-copy-assignment-operator-is-implicitly-deleted)

Comment: Side note: you can get rid of all those redundant explicit dereferences of `this` (`this->`), it's only (rarely) needed in templates to make other types dependant names (and in a few other equally rare situations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes that have reference or const non-static data members (or non- assignable base-class sub-objects or non-static data members) are non-assignable by default, because reference is not reseatable, const is immutable and non-assignable component non-assignable. IOW these have their default `operator=` deleted.

We see:

```
class Object 
{
    /* ... */
    ObjectProgram& _program;
}
```

That `_program` is reference so  default `operator=` of `Object` it is deleted. You got to provide custom  `operator=` or not to try to assign it.

Comment: So if I understood this right, I have to make a custom = operator for the Object class ?

Comment: in that custom operator= you still won't be able to change the reference

Comment: @Lauriane  Or change `ObjectProgram& _program; ` to `ObjectProgram* _program;`  and use a pointer to observe the `ObjectProgram`.

Comment: @maxim1000   Such a custom `operator=()` does not attempt to "reseat" the reference, so the reference refers to the same object through life of the containing `Object`.   If that is not the behaviour sought in the assignment operator, then a reference member is the wrong choice (and one option, as Richard noted is using a pointer, since - unlike a reference - a pointer CAN be reassigned, as well as not suppressing implicit generation of an `operator=()`).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the compiler warnings the member variable with a reference type [prevents any assignment operators from being implicitly defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator).

```
ObjectProgram& _program;
```

Note that this does not mean the implicitly defined move constructor is deleted too. This is the reason why `std::vector<Wanderer>::push_back` works: If the backing storage needs to be reallocated, the existing objects are moved over to the new storage by using the move constructor with placement `new`.

Your options of fixing this issue are limited:

- Make `_program` a pointer, `std::reference_wrapper`, or similar allowing for the implicilty created move constructor to be defined.
- Change the type of `gaspard` to something that doesn't require the assignment operator, e.g. `std::optional<Wanderer>` allowing you to use [`std::optional<Wanderer>::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace) for the initialization.